# Get text from a textbox in one form and insert it in a textbox from other form

Tags: c#, forms, text, textbox, get

I'm very new to C# language, so please take me easy. What I want to ask is quite simple, but being new, I don't know how to do it.

I have 2 forms: Form1 and Form2. Form1 is the "default" one, the one you have when you open the application. I have 2 textboxes in the second form and two buttons (ok and cancel). In the first form I have a button which opens the 2nd form when you click on it and a textbox. I tried to get the text from those 2 textboxes in form 2 and to put it in the textbox from form1, but I didn't managed to do it. I want when I click ok in the second form, the text from those 2 textboxes in form 2 to be put in the textbox from form1 and when I click cancel, to just simply close form2. Can you help me?

Comment: Yet another question similar to e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806795/how-to-change-text-in-a-textbox-on-another-form-in-visual-c?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

You could create a public property in Form2 that is set by Form1 when you press your button.

```
public string TextValueFromForm1 { get; set; }
```

On the Form Load event, you could then, set the value of your text box to that of the property.

**Example of Form 2**

```
public class Form2 : Form
{
    private TextBox textBox1;
    private TextBox textBox2;

    public string TextValue1 { get; set; }
    public string TextValue2 { get; set; }

    public Form2()
    {
        this.Load += new EventHandler((object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        {
            textBox1.Text = TextValue1;
            textBox2.Text = TextValue2;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Anyway, I managed to solve it; I don't know if I asked correctly, but this is how I did : I created a public string in 'public partial class Form2' that retains the text from those 2 textboxes and then I was able to access it from Form1. I think I must also say that class Form1 and Form2 inherits everything from class Form.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question:
 - Form2 has 2 TextBoxes (`textBox1` and `textBox2`) and 2 buttons (`btnOK` and `btnCancel`)
 - If `btnOK` is pressed - concatinate values of `textBox1` and `textBox2` and pass them to `Form1`
 - If `btnCancel` is pressed - do not pass any data

**Brief description of my answer:**
 It can be easily achieved with event handlers, just hook up to `OnFormClosing` event and read data from predefined property of `Form2`

Some code to illustrate my answer is below

**Form1.cs**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
            frm2.Show();
            frm2.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(frm2_FormClosing);
        }

        void frm2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((sender as Form2).textData != null)
                textBox1.Text = (sender as Form2).textData;
        }
    }
```

**Form2.cs**

```
 public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public string textData;
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textData = textBox1.Text + " " + textBox2.Text;
            this.Close();
        }

        private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Anyway, I managed to solve it; I don't know if I asked correctly, but this is how I did : I created a public string in 'public partial class Form2' that retains the text from those 2 textboxes and then I was able to access it from Form1. I think I must also say that class Form1 and Form2 inherits everything from class Form.