# How can I create a link between text boxes using C# or C++?

Tags: c#, c++

How can I create a link between text boxes? I am working on my Accounting Project in which I have to link the multiple sheets and their data.

I am using multiple panels on a single from and there are many simple text boxes on my panels so the main thing I want here is that if I made change in one textbox it automatically updates the value of other textboxes linked with that.

Comment: This link may be helpful for you [clickhere](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806795/how-to-change-text-in-a-textbox-on-another-form-in-visual-c)

Answer (score 1):

Assume there are 4 textboxes. You can bind them as follows:

```
textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", textBox2, "Text", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
textBox2.DataBindings.Add("Text", textBox3, "Text", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
textBox3.DataBindings.Add("Text", textBox4, "Text", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

Now when you change the text in any of them there will be changes in all.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean automatically updates the value of other textboxes? There are no magic behind, just a code. So what you have to do is write some code. Call event on main text box OnTextChange and after that inside the function something like myTextBox1_OnTextChange()  update the other control.