# Access text box from another form in C# - note, the form that I'm looking to set the box for is the first form

Tags: c#, .net

So this is a bit different to what I've seen:

[How to change text in a textbox on another form in Visual C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806795/how-to-change-text-in-a-textbox-on-another-form-in-visual-c)

I have a form (Form1) that runs when my C# application runs. A button Form1 opens Form2. On Form2, I have another button to set the text of the textbox on Form1, to the same value as a textbox on Form2.

Using a similar approach to:

Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
    frm1.TextBoxValue = "SomeValue";

Doesn't work as it opens a new form completely, but I want to change the form1 that is already open, can someone please assist?

Comment: If you want to work with an existing form, you dont use `new` to create a new instance.  use the one that is already open

Comment: All the open forms (including the main one) are kept by the framework in the Application.OpenForms collection. You just need to search that collection for a form with  the Type matching the desidered one.

Comment: This question gets asked 100x every day and gets answered and any of those answers should work for you.

Answer (score 2):

You must store `Textbox`value on Form2 in some property like this:

```
public string ReturnValue {get;set;} 

private void Form2_button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     ReturnValue = txtInput.Text;
}
```

Or You can change the access modifier for the generated field in `Form2.Designer.cs` from private to public.

Change this

```
private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txtInput;
```

by this

```
public System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txtInput;
```

Then in `Form1` you can get Value of `ReturnValue` When end user close `Form2`

```
private void Form1_popupButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Form2 frm = new  Form2();
       frm.ShowDialog();

      // get ReturnValue from form2
      string ReturnValue = frm.ReturnValue ;
      //get txtInput value directly
      ReturnValue = frm.txtInput.Text;
}
```

Comment: Yes this is exactly what my edit was getting at.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to help you as good as I can but the information you provided is not that clear to me.

What you could do is when creating a new form use the constructor to pass the text

E.G.

```
Form1 frm1 = new Form1("some value or variable");
```

When you need tailored information please provide more code and a better explanation of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a constructor for Form2 that takes in Form1 as a parent:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    Form1 Parent { get; }
    public Form2(Form1 parent)
    {
        Parent = parent;
        Parent.TextBoxValue = "SomeValue";
    }
}
```

However I don't think this is good practice.  If your Form2 needs to be passing a result back to Form1, then you need to reverse your approach.  Instead you should have a public property or method on *Form2* that you can assign from inside *Form1*.

Comment: Note that `Form` already has a `Parent` property

Comment: Yeah good point.  Probably for the best anyway since I feel like OP is trying to do this backwards.