# How to save WPF textbox value to variable

Tags: c#, wpf

Im trying to make a WPF based program that will read the textbox input (user input) from a usercontrol and save it as a `object` proprety. The usercontrol is added to `MainWindow`. From `MainWindow`, you have a button which displays a message box with the textbox value. I'm not sure how to connect it all.

> Error = CS0103    The name 'minJpValue' does not exist in the current
>   context   WpfApp1

Please help

1. (Usercontrol .xaml code)

   ```
   <TextBox x:Name="minJpValue"/>
   ```
2. (Custom class)

   ```
   public class jpData 
   {
       public double minJpValue
       {
           get { return minJpValue; }
           set { minJpValue = value; }
       }
   }
   ```
3. (MainWindow .cs code)

   ```
   private void clickclick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       MessageBox.Show(minJpValue);
   }
   ```

Comment: First of all you should add in custom class world 
_return minJpValue.Text
minJpValue.Text = value_ since you want Text value

Comment: You should probably start a simple WPF application without a UserControl. Then learn things step by step, perhaps with the help of a WPF book like e.g. Adam Nathan's "WPF Unleashed".

Comment: If you give the `UserControl` element an `x:Name` of for example "uc" in the XAML markup of the window, you could access the value of the `TextBox` using `uc.minJpValue`.

Comment: Also this could help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806795/how-to-change-text-in-a-textbox-on-another-form-in-visual-c and check textbox public property

Comment: You have not given us anywhere near enough code to determine exactly what your issue is - although we could guess, Stack Overflow isn't about guessing or giving huge long tutorials.

Comment: I suggest you start with basic console applications first so you learn the ropes of operating with objects and how to access object members (such as fields, properties, methods). Only after you got the basics internalized, begin to learn WPF (or any other UI toolkit of your choice). I fear you put quite a lot on your plate right now, requiring you to learn many things at once just to get a simple program to compile and, even more difficult, to work properly...

Comment: If I use the textbox code in MainWindows.xaml it works:

<TextBox Name="MinJpValue" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Margin="3" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>

If copy exactly the same code to Usercontrol1.xaml I get the message mentioned.

So in first case the popup message displays the data entered, in second case it doesnt work.

Comment: WPF has a **XAML namescope**. The control that has x:Name set is only visible within a certain scope. This is the parent control, where the named child control is defined. And  only this parent control. Outside this control the given name doesn't exist. Please read [Microsoft Docs: x:Name Directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/xaml-services/x-name-directive) and maybe [NameScope In C-Sharp And WPF](https://dzone.com/articles/c-and-wpf-namescope-my-name-is).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue can be easily fixed using the MVVM Patterns, 
The code for the usercontrol will be similar to this

```
<Grid Background="Red">
    <TextBox x:Name="minJpValue" Text="{Binding Path=minJpValue}" />
</Grid>
```

Create new ViewModel for the MainWindow as follows

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Property Changed Event Handler
    /// </summary>
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    // Create the OnPropertyChanged method to raise the event
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
   private String _minJpValue;
    public String minJpValue {
        get { return _minJpValue; }
        set {
            _minJpValue = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(minJpValue));
        }
    }

}
```

Add the usercontrol into your MainWindow view and in the codebehind set the datacontext to the ViewModel as follows

```
 public MainWindowViewModel CurrentModel = new MainWindowViewModel();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = CurrentModel;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(CurrentModel.minJpValue);
    }
```

This can solve your current problem. Please see that its working as per expected.

Comment: Thank you Ashok, onpropertychanged event was the solution that worked for me

Answer (score 1):

For this quick fix use:

```
 MessageBox.Show(minJpValue.Text);
```

---

But a better way would be to store the value on a `VM` (View Model) and bind the control to it using the MVVM pattern. I provide a basic example on

[Xaml: ViewModel Main Page Instantiation and Loading Strategy for Easier Binding](http://omegacoder.com/?p=1017)

Comment: He mentioned `minJpValue` is in user control and he wanna display it in MainWindow I don't think this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok let's Understand wt have u done wrong.

`<TextBox Name="minJpValue"/>`

This line of will Create an object for TextBox and the object will be referred with ur name 
`minJpValue` as u mentioned this will be inside another `Usercontrol` object and u r try to `minJpValue` in `MainWindow` how does it even know that something like `minJpValue` this exists

**So Here is the answer:**

```
objjpData.minJpValue = minJpValue.Text;//Inside user control when ever u change the `minJpValue` u need to set it too bjjpData.minJpValue
```

pass this `objjpData` to mainwindow or where u wanna acesses then

`MessageBox.Show(objjpData.minJpValue);`

**Option 2:**
MessageBox.Show(UserControlObject.minJpValue.Text);

And PS: Check MVVM once

Comment: What is `objjpData` and how do you pass it to the main window? I think that's the key to this problem. Whether  you use `VisualTreeHelper` or `Binding` (e.g. `RelativeSource FindAncestor`) to get the parent main window, you must at least spend the main window a property e.g. of type `string`. To get the text from the `TextBox` is the 'obvious'  part I would say.

Comment: @BionicCode U can create an `objjpData` in the main window and pass it to user control. it's completely dependent on his code. and I don't really think he is using Binding.  I don't wanna make the answer complicated

Comment: To provide a working solution I suggest to ad a `DependencyProperty` of type `string` to the `MainWindow` called `Message`. Then bind the `TextBox` from the the `UserControl` to this property by using `{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType MainWindow}`. Add a property chanegd callback to the new `Message` property that will show the message.

Comment: Yes, okay. But I don't think your example is going to help. It doesn't solve the problem. You wrapped the text into a variable instead passing it directly. This is not a solution.

Comment: @BionicCode he wants the data in that variable too right (mentioned in question (how-to-save-wpf-textbox-value-to-variable)) so that why I mentioned like that. and if there is a better answer please add it even I will be happy to read it

Comment: @BionicCode and his problem is  **Error = CS0103 The name 'minJpValue' does not exist in the current context WpfApp1** I'm sure it will be solved